# How to find the minimal number of steps to make an array contain all identical elements?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have an array of N items, example:

```
4 2 1 1
```

I want to make all the numbers the same in minimum operations, and i can perform only one type of  operation:

If I Add 1 to any number then I have to subtract 1 from another one

In our example: adding 1 to 4th element and subtracting 1 from the first one

```
3 2 1 2
```

adding 1 to 3rd element and subtracting 1 from 1st one

```
2 2 2 2

array element can be 0 but not a negative number
```

And i am coding this in c++ .

Comment: I think code can solve it. (And being less sarcastic: what did you try?)

Comment: @Aman, Neil Kirk is simply obfuscating my answer so Idont get an up vote. You can use myanswer.

Comment: I want a general algorithm . Not for only this array

Comment: @aman, you can use *0, mine,or the avg like below. Thats all there is.

Comment: `modf()` would be good here too, but you'd need to use 2 operations.

Comment: Otherwise, you don'tknow how to code at all, and you're waiting for us to do your homework. So I'm not doing anymore to help.

Answer (score 6):

Here are some hints:

1. Each operation decreases 1 and increases 1 to the total sum of elements, so the total sum does not change.
2. Since `average = sum / n` - this means the average also does not change.
3. when `a1=a2=...=an`, they all also equal to the average.

Use these hints, and you can figure out an algorithm to do that.

Comment: I tried to upvote you, but I've downvoted so much rubbish recently that I've hit the limit for now:(